# Append text to a rich text box at a certain interval of time in C#

Tags: c#, text, time, richtextbox, wait

I'm trying to write some sort of a log to an algorithm. That is, while the simulation is running, I want to add a text to the log, saying what is going on in the simulation (at let's say 2 seconds time from the previous add).

I've tried using

`Thread.Sleep(2000);`

but this just makes the entire text appear in the log at the end of the simulation after number_of_loops x 2 seconds.

What else can I try?

Comment: Isn't every 2 seconds kind of arbitrary?  Would it not be better to log each time something actually happens?

Comment: things happen very fast, it's a simple simulation :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a timer control, [see this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/43daf8b2-67ad-4938-98f7-cae3eaa5e63f/) for a walkthrough.  Put your updating code into the `tick` method.

Comment: Correct. A WinForms app will want to use the [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) class. You can add one of these timers to your form at design time (see the "Components" section in the toolbox), or instantiate it with code. Set the timer's `Interval` property to however many milliseconds you want to wait between updates.

Answer (score -1):

This should do this:

```
public void updateMessage()
{
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

    while (DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).Seconds < 15)
    {
        //do your update here
        textbox.text+="STATUS";
    }
}
Thread threadUpdating=new Thread(new ThreadStart(updateMessage));;
threadUpdating.Start();
```

Comment: Nope. `Sleep` locks up the thread, and `Application.DoEvents` is **never** a good idea. This is the wrong answer.

Comment: @Cody Gray -edited, and why Application.DoEvents is a bad idea?

Comment: Because there's almost always a simpler and better solution; in this case, a Timer. The only people who are safe putting a call to `Application.DoEvents` in their code are those who understand *exactly* what it does (and I don't mean "makes the app more responsive", I mean that it pumps the Windows message queue and all of the possible side effects of that). Those people tend to be the ones who change their design or find another, better method of doing this. It's often recommended as a quick, easy solution on here, but it's just not. 70% of my downvotes are to answers suggesting it.

Comment: The truth is that threading is hard and masquerading `DoEvents` as an easy solution to those problems is disingenuous at best, and leads to difficult to debug re-entrancy bugs later. What happens when the user clicks something they're not supposed to that disrupts your operation? There's just too much you have to consider to make this a safe proposal, yet it's often recommended to those who don't know what those things are. It's a hack for debugging purposes maybe, but that's about all it's worth. More information is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/08/06/448560.aspx).

Comment: @Cody Gray you dont have to be that harsh...anyway i corrected the solution.

Comment: @Blue Gene, I don't think Cody has been harsh at all - it is constructive advice which would be to your benefit if you take it on board.